# How to pass data during a res.redirect?

Tags: node.js, express

My view relies on some data to render, like this:

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render(
        'index', {
            data: layout_data,
            user: req.user
        }
    );
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

It works. But when I added the **csurf** middleware like

```
router.post('/login', parseForm, csrfProtection, passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

The layout engine tells me that `data` is undefined. I suspect that the csurf middleware erases the data.

I tried to fix it like this:

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    req.mydata = {};
    req.mydata.layout_data = layout_data;
    res.render(
        'index', {
            data: req.mydata.layout_data,
            user: req.user
        }
    );
});

router.post('/login', parseForm, csrfProtection, passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
    if (!req.mydata) {
        req.mydata = {};
    }
    req.mydata.layout_data = layout_data;
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

It still does not work. The data is still undefined.

What is the best practice to resolve this problem?

Comment: When you redirect a URL, it turns into a GET request. In GET request, you need to use URL queries instead.

Comment: @Paras, but it works when I removed `csrfProtection` from the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is: your `layout_data` is undefined.